# is there a way to filter devices list

Tags: android-management-api

i'm using android management api and i can limit fields returned **but i do not find a way to filter query results.**

for example, is there a way with enterprises.devices.list method to get only devices matching one specific policy or hardware brand?

https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to filter the result when using enterprises.devices.list as it will list all devices assigned on the given enterprise.

Comment: so we need to sync list in emm db  to allow such queries. Is Pub/Sub notifications on status reports the best way to keep this db sync?